# where is chunkingbehavior attribute in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, reference

I am looking at this article that describes chunking in wcf services. 
[link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx)

I cannot locate the reference dll for `ChunkingBehavior` attrribute. Do you know which dll I should add to the solution?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to download the samples from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21459 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in Microsoft sample. You can view code [here](https://crazyworship.svn.codeplex.com/svn/CrazyWorship1/ChunkingChannel/CS/ChunkingChannel/ChunkingBehavior.cs)

You should read notes in article(especially marked with exclamation mark):

> The samples may already be installed on your machine. Check for the following (default) directory before continuing.
>   InstallDrive:\WF_WCF_Samples
>   If this directory does not exist, go to Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) and Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) Samples for .NET Framework 4 to download all Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) and WF samples. This sample is located in the following directory.

Comment: oh alright. I thought chunking classes existed as independent packaged dll's.  thanks for the answer...

Answer (score 1):

It's included in source code in the samples as part of that document you've linked to.

The installer for those Samples can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21459).